# will_paginate and having problems getting to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, will-paginate

I'm getting errors on will_paginate such as: undefined method `paginate' for # in my rails app.

I'm trying to do the simplest possible query such as:

```
@results = Location.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

or

```
@results = Location.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('name')
```

`Location.order('name')` works fine in console

Any ideas what is going on or next steps? Does anything need to be added to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured everything as outlined in the docs? I remember when I first got started with rails and will_paginate, I had to restart the web server for everything to work.